# Set TextView text with string from another class

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a java class where I stored a string like:

```
public class MyStrings
{
    public static String test = "";
}
```

This string's value is set with a value from a database, and using the debug mode I could see that the string had the value I wanted.

Now I want to set the Text of a TextView with this *test* string from the java class.

Unfortunately doing so, doesn't work and TextView Text results empty:

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.labelTitle);
title.setText(MyStrings.test);
```

Here is the function where I initialize my variable:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
    MyStrings.test = result;
}
```

The *result* String is returned by this function:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String action = params[0];
    String login_url = "login.php";

    if(action.equals("login"))
    {
        try
        {
            String email = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result = "";
            String line = "";
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to create a singleton class and see if that helps

Comment: I don't think there is enough information to know what the problem is. Because when I call a String from another class, it displays in the TextView.

Comment: It is difficult to tell you where is the problem if you don't provide your code

Comment: @E.Abdel, that's actually the code. It's just missing the assignation, but it shouldn't be a big deal.. I'll add it

Comment: Is the async task in your activity?

Comment: Not enough information to help us help you, more related code please

Comment: @E.Abdel, no it's not. But what I don't understand is:
if that String has the value I wanted, why is the TextView not displaying it? Did I set the text in a wrong way?

Comment: Ok, I found out that I was setting TextView's Text in the method onCreate, doing so text doesn't change, but on an onClick function it works fine. Now my question is: how do I set text when activity loads?

Comment: put your code in onResume method

Comment: @E.Abdel, I added onResume() method as you suggested, but the text won't change anyway.
`@Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        title.setText(MyStrings.test);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

A\c to the information you have provided, you are setting text in textView when myString.text value is empty that's why it is setting only Empty Text,
You can set text in onPostCreate() of AsyncTask then it will set the Text.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result){
 MyStrings.test = result;  //if you want to assign then you can assign
title.setText(MyStrings.test);
}
```

Comment: I can't setText from this java class. It extends AsyncTask

Comment: Just create a constructor in AsyncTask class and pass activity context through that constructor. Now with the help of context you can access textview object and then in onPostCreate() you can set text in textView.